# How do I work out the difference in numbers when reading and writing to text files in python?

Tags: python, text-files

Alright, so I am studying python as a hobby, and I need to write a program that: should look at data for each student and calculate the number of marks a student needs to achieve the minimum score when they re-sit their exam. So I am going to say that the minimum score that a user needs to pass their exam is 85, and if a student record says 80, they would need 5. I have written the text file, and started the python code, but I have hit a dead end, any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Python:

```
def menu():
with open('homework.txt','r') as a_file:
    contents_of_file = a_file.read()
print(contents_of_file)
input()
```

Text file:

```
emma smith,79
noah jones,32
olivia williams,26
liam taylor,91
sophia green,80
mason brown,98
```

Comment: Reading the file line-by-line and splitting it from the `,` to end?

Comment: you should really look into the pandas package, great for manipulating text files

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading the whole file at once, we will look at each line individually.  We'll use `split` to divide the lines into a name and a number, then use `int` to convert the string of a number into a numeric type.

```
def menu(): 
    target = 85   
    with open('homework.txt','r') as a_file:
        for l in a_file:
            name, number = l.split(',')
            number = int(number)
            print(name + ': '  + ('passed' if number>=target else str(target - number)))
    input()
```

`('passed' if number>=target else str(target - number))` is just a way of doing an if statement in one line for simple things

Answer (score 0):

There is other possibilities and shorter ways, but to give you a basic understanding, this might help: This should read each line and split it at the comma.

```
with open('homework.txt','r') as a_file:
    for line in a_file.readlines():
        split_line=line.split(",")
        name=split_line[0]
        score=split_line[1]
        YOUR CODE HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas package is great for manipulating text files like yours. While it might be overkill for your current scenario, it may be useful to learn.

```
import pandas as pd

marks_needed = 85
df = pd.read_csv('homework.txt', header=None)

for name, marks in df.values:
    if marks > marks_needed:
        print('{} passed!'.format(name)
    else:
        extra_marks = marks_needed - marks
        print('{} needs {} more marks'.format(name, extra_marks))
```